# Animating the steps of a Kohonen SOM in Mathematica

Tags: animation

As the title suggest, I'm trying to make an animation of how a bunch of points into 2-D (and possibly 3-D space) evolves by each step of my program.

In order to do so I've data which contains the x and y position of every single point of the map at a given "time" t, which is defined by jumping over 20 elements of the list.

i.e. t=0 goes from row 1 to row 20, t=1 from row 21 to row 40, etc...

here's the file:
Full Version:
https://www.mediafire.com/?irgddwos6qn5kb1
Light Version:
https://www.mediafire.com/?rdx66fsyzejonhx

and here's what i've written in order to obtain x and y positions of points at a given time:

```
    dati = Import["...\\KOHONEN SOM\\output.dat"]
    {a, b} = Transpose[dati];
    neuro = 20;
    x = Array[h, neuro];
    y = Array[j, neuro];
    Table[x[[k]] = Table[a[[k + i*neuro*4]], {i, 0, 50000}], {k, 1, neuro}];
    Table[y[[k]] = Table[b[[k + i*neuro*4]], {i, 0, 50000}], {k, 1, neuro}];
    X = Array[l, 50000];
    Y = Array[s, 50000];
    Table[X[[l]] = Table[x[[j]][[l]], {j, 1, neuro}], {l, 1, 50000}];
    Table[Y[[l]] = Table[y[[j]][[l]], {j, 1, neuro}], {l, 1, 50000}];
```

Note that the i*neuro*4 thing is in order to take a little less of all the data i have

I've also been able to make plots of each evolution step, as shown here:

```
 POW = Table[
   ListPlot[Transpose[{X[[l]], Y[[l]]}], PlotRange -> All], {l, 1,
     50000}];
```

This allows me to have the single frames of the animation, but yet, I haven't been able to combine them into an animation.

Moreover, I was looking for having the points connected by a line in the animation itself, so that, if I'd start increasing the numbers of neuro, it wouldn't be a mess to understand what's going on...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you come up with a short working example showing your issue?

Comment: if you download my file and run that little program of mine, you'll see that i can produce a lot of images with points on them, in a 2-D space (since the output.dat contains 2 columns of x and y data). I'd like to put them into an animation, which shows the evolution of the points in the 2-D space, if possible, aving those dots connected by a line. At the moment i don't have an example, since all I'm doing with the animation stuff just doesn't work

Comment: It's a 80MB file, if it's contains two columns of x and y data I'm sure you can reduce the number of rows to make it < 1MB.

Comment: I can indeed: https://www.mediafire.com/?rdx66fsyzejonhx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dati = Import["~/Downloads/output2.dat"];
{a, b} = Transpose[dati];
neuro = 20;
x = Array[h, neuro];
y = Array[j, neuro];
itLength = Floor[Length@a/(neuro*4)];
Table[x[[k]] = Table[a[[k + i*neuro*4]], {i, 0, itLength}], {k, 1, neuro}];
Table[y[[k]] = Table[b[[k + i*neuro*4]], {i, 0, itLength}], {k, 1, neuro}];
X = Array[l, itLength];
Y = Array[s, itLength];
Table[X[[l]] = Table[x[[j]][[l]], {j, 1, neuro}], {l, 1, itLength}];
Table[Y[[l]] = Table[y[[j]][[l]], {j, 1, neuro}], {l, 1, itLength}];
POW = Table[
   ListLinePlot[Transpose[{X[[l]], Y[[l]]}], PlotRange -> {0, 20}, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Hue[Rescale[l, {0, itLength}]]], {l, 1, itLength, 10}]
```

Then, all you have to do is to `Export` it as a `GIF`:

```
Export["~/animated.gif", POW, "DisplayDurations" -> .1]
```

[image]

Comment: that's what i was looking for, i only wish to know if ther's a way to have fixed axes

Comment: @Andrea `PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 20}}` :)

Comment: oh right, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematica* has lots of tools to handle exactly what you seem to want to do.  (See [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) for some links and pointers.)  Your code basically uses [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html) as a for-loop, which is not what it is designed for.  [`For`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/For.html) does that.  But there are much more concise and clearer ways to achieve what you want.  (Well, clearer once the basic idea of a couple of functions are known.)

There are three or four I'll use.

- [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html), which will partition your data into sets of `neuro = 20` groups.  Then your "time" index `t` can be used with `datp[[t]]`: `datp[[1]`, `datp[[2]]`, etc.
- [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html) (`;;`), which can be used to select a subrange from a list or array, including skipping so many elements each time.
- [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) (`/@`), which can be used to apply a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) (`ListLinePlot[#,...] &` in the case below) to each element of a list.

Then your code can be rewritten like this:

```
dati = Import["~/Downloads/output.dat"];
neuro = 20;
datp = Partition[dati, neuro];
pow = ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 20}}] & /@ datp[[1 ;; All ;; 4]]
```

The keyword `All` is very convenient here.  You don't even have to know how much data you have.  (Many people use `-1` instead of `All`.  The `-1` indicates the last element.)  The `4` is how many elements to skip each time.  For the full data set, you might want to start with a much larger value, like `400` or `2000` to get a quick overview.

---

Further tips:

It's more efficient to work with large amounts of data as [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array), if possible.  Your imported data will not be packed, but it can be via:

```
dati = Developer`ToPackedArray @ Import["~/Downloads/output.dat"];
```

You can save it in a much more efficient form with [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DumpSave.html) (with the semicolon to suppress printing `dati`).

```
DumpSave["file.mx", dati];
```

You can reload it (packed, if it was saved as a packed array) with [`Get`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Get.html):

```
Get["file.mx"]
```

Or you can save `datp`, which might be more convenient.

Comment: well, thanks a lot, that's a lot of advices! and it looks like using them would have saved me a lot of time in my previous notebooks... thanks again!

Comment: @Andrea You're welcome. :)